# Projection matrix for three dimension matrices

Tags: matrices, projection-matrices

I am working on the projection matrix (i.e, let $M_A=I-A(A^\prime A)^{-1}A^\prime$, then $M_A A=0$, here $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is a two dimension matrix, and assume the dimensions match). What about the projection matrix of $A$ if now $A$ is assumed to be a $m\times n \times k$? Can we find a projection matrix of the 3D matrix $A$ such that $MA=0$? Thanks

Comment: For a "3D matrix", then how is matrix-multiplication defined?

Comment: Thanks for that. In my regression model it is defined as $Ab=B$ where $A$ is a $m\times n\times k$ matrix, while $b$ is a $k\times 1$ vector and  $B$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. I am not sure this is a good way to define matrix multiplication.